# Operators and inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, operator-overloading

My brain has turned to jelly, or I'm having an *out of mind experience*, or something. I'm tinkering with a class hierarchy that looks a bit like this:
[image]

My `Money` class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Money
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Money leftSide, Money rightSide)
    {
        // Money can only be equal if it is in the same currency.
        if (leftSide.GetType() != rightSide.GetType()) return false;
        return leftSide.Amount == rightSide.Amount;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Money leftSide, Money rightSide)
    {
        // If the currencies are different, the amounts are always considered unequal.
        if (leftSide.GetType() != rightSide.GetType()) return true;
        return leftSide.Amount != rightSide.Amount;
    }

    public static Money operator *(Money multiplicand, int multiplier)
    {
        var result = multiplicand * multiplier;
        return result;
    }

    public static Dollar Dollar(int amount)
    {
        return new Dollar(amount);
    }

    public static Franc Franc(int amount)
    {
        return new Franc(amount);
    }
}
```

My Dollar `operator *` looks like this:

```
public static Dollar operator *(Dollar multiplicand, int multiplier)
{
    var result = multiplicand.Amount * multiplier;
    return new Dollar(result);
}
```

Now, if I run this test code, I get a Stack overflow (wahoo!)

```
{
    Money fiveDollars = Money.Dollar(5);
    Money timesTwo = fiveDollars*2;
}
```

I had expected that this would recursively call the subclass (Dollar) `operator *`, which would return a definite result since (Dollar * int) is defined non-recursively. Since this doesn't work, the alternative is that I have done something dumb. Why doesn't this work? What would be the right way to get this behaviour?

Comment: When you get a stack overflow, you should examine the stack.  You'll see the same functions calling each other over and over again.  That alone will tell you a lot about whats happening and why.

Comment: Note that the recursion occurs because you are actually invoking `Money.operator*`, not `Dollar.operator*`. Operators are *overloaded*, not *overridden*, and so the function that is invoked is determined by the *compile-time* types of the operands, not the *run-time* types. Since `fiveDollars` is a variable of type `Money`, `fiveDollars * 2` invokes the `Money` version of `operator*` (even though the *run-time* type of `fiveDollars` is `Dollar`.)

Answer (score 11):

You seem to have left out `.Amount`

```
public static Money operator *(Money multiplicand, int multiplier)
{
    var result = multiplicand.Amount * multiplier;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you expect that you can *override* operators in derived classes and expect [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). This is not the way it works in C#. Operators are *overloaded* and the actual overload is chosen compile-time. This means that the following code **is** recursive and calls itself:

```
public static Money operator *(Money multiplicand, int multiplier)
{
    var result = multiplicand * multiplier;
    return result;
}
```

Another example where you can see the difference between operator overloading and method overriding  is this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;

Console.WriteLine(a == b); // true
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // true
Console.WriteLine((object)a == (object)b); // false
Console.WriteLine(((object)a).Equals((object)b)); // true
```

In the third case, C# treats `a` and `b` as objects instead of integers, so it uses the default `==` operator that is used for objects: comparing references (in this case the references of boxed integers).

This can make it awkward to define operators on a class hierarchy where you want to redefine the operators in derived classes. It is especially awkward when the behavior depends on the combination of both operands, since C# (and most other OOP languages) lacks support for [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). You can solve this by using the visitor pattern, but I think in this case you should reconsider if using subclasses for each currency is the best solution.

Comment: +1 Yes, that would indeed seem to be the problem. I _did_ think operators were overridden, I've learned something here :)